# dir(all.files = FALSE) and visible files

Tags: r

Based on documentation:

```
dir(path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,
    full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
    ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE)


all.files: a logical value.  If 'FALSE', only the names of visible
          files are returned.  If 'TRUE', all file names will be
          returned.
```

Actually, at least on Win7 x64, with:

```
dir(all.files = FALSE)
```

I get listed  also files with `attrib` set to:

```
_HSA_________
```

With:

```
dir (all.files = TRUE)
```

I get *also* the nonsensical directory *placeholders*:

```
[1] "."            ".."
```

What about you ?

## Update: Solution, design strategy, or bug?

After some further investigations, I can give some (hopefully) useful insights. 
As many of you know, in Linux the file starting with a “dot” are considered hidden, this is not the case in Windows, which is based on attributes. (The `dir()` function of) R follows the Linux convention. On Windows this can cause a number of problems.

If you issue a standard `dir()`, i.e. if you query for visible files, you get also hidden ones and, more seriously, you may not get the visible files, just because they start with an innocent dot, which in Windows has no particular meaning. 
This means that in Windows the standard `dir()` is simply no use, unless you are operating in a controlled environment where you are sure there are no dot-files.

`dir (all.files = TRUE)` can be partially useful, assuming that you are not interested in excluding hidden/system file. But this is true only for an interactive use. 
`dir (all.files = TRUE)` always adds two fake files named `.` and `..` (well, always except for root). This means that a line like this, to check for directory emptiness, won’t work on Windows:

```
 if (length(dir(all.files = TRUE))==0) cat('I am empty\n')
```

**Is this behaviour implemented by design?**

One may answer that it is, since R `dir()` replicates in this way the Windows shell command `dir`. 
IMHO shell `dir` is not intended primarily for batch use; while R commands should be intended for programming tasks. 
And anyway why does this replicating behaviour show only when `all.files = TRUE`?

One thing is for sure that, R coders are always so kind in detailing the differences among different OS’s in the documentations, while in this case (
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/list.files.html) the word "Windows" never appears.

What is your opinion? Am I missing something? Or is it the case of submitting an actual bug?

Comment: what's `attrib`? I see the placeholders with all.files=TRUE. These go away with all.files=FALSE. I don't know what you're talking about with '_HSA___'. Perhaps it's a file that's actually there, but is hidden in Explorer?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: On MS Windows `attrib foo` shows file properties. `attrib +HS foo` makes file foo `Hidden` and `System`, basically not visible. If I set a file like this, I still can get it via `dir()`

Comment: First: You are wrong in saying that dotfiles are visible by default in Windows. Search on "hidden files" in Windows docs.  Second: Before you submit a "bug" you should be advised that R Core will not consider it a bug unless you can show errors in the code. If you suggest revisions to the `list.files` help page, you should  offer specific suggestions for different wording that you feel would make the situation more clear.

Comment: @DWin: I did the search, as you asked, and I got this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/What-is-a-hidden-file Such hidden files are showed when you use `all.files = FALSE`, despite the documentation says “If 'FALSE', only the names of visible files are returned”. I am not claiming it is a bug (there is a question mark in the header). Anyway potential "errors" depend in general on what is the intended behaviour, which in this particular case depends on the definition of “hidden/visible file”.

Answer (score 1):

The "." and the ".." are placeholders for the containing directory and the "root". They represent what you would get at a Windows command line if you did:

```
 cd .
 cd ..
```

The help file makes it clear that R is displaying what is returned by the OS. Perhaps you should also e reviewing the Windows documentation. I would start with the documentation for the Windows "dir" command.

Comment: I know this. I will try to make this clear later, now I am fast, sorry. Very shortly: if you ask for visible files in R, you get also OS-non-visible files. If you ask for non-visible in R, you get also OS placeholders, that are not meaningful and disturbing if you are parsing the result for test empty dirs. It's a nasty conflict with the `.` meaning in R/Linux world and Windows.

Comment: @antonio I think what R does is right here, as it copies `ls -a`

Answer (score 1):

@antonio thanks for the clarification. The term 'visible' in the documentation seems to refer to files not starting with a period, not necessarily files that are not 'hidden', in the sense of their Windows attrib. Apparently, calling `dir` in R is not the same as calling it from the Windows command line.

This really isn't a problem, though, since you can just call the Windows dir directly to get the behavior you want:

```
shell('dir /b', intern=TRUE)
```

Or if your goal is simply to be able to easily determine whether a directory is empty, you can use:

```
file.info('New folder')$size == 0
```

Comment: Mmmm, difficult to say, perhaps the problem is that it is too similar. The dot placeholders are what the shell itself uses, but IMHO it should be better to divert from this. Your workaround is good, but I am more trying to get some feedback, to see if we should possibly submit the question to developers for review.

Comment: @antonio I don't really understand what you're trying to say. On Windows, R's `dir` function won't return filenames starting with a period, if `all.files=FALSE`. It will, however, return files with the hidden attrib, regardless of whether `all.files` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If you want to ignore these files, call Windows `dir` program with the appropriate flags directly via R's `shell` function, as I've shown here. The behavior of the R `dir` is desirable, since it will be the same regardless of the OS.

Comment: If you main concern is being able to easily determine if a file is empty, use `file.info('New folder')$size == 0`

Comment: @antonio, just saw your edits to the question, you can ignore my first comment here. But take a look at `file.info`, it's a platform agnostic way to check if a directory's empty.